# How to share HTML between components?

Tags: angular

I want to share some HTML (layout) between some of my components but not all.

**app.compomonent.html:**

```html
<div class="classA">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Some of my components, but not all, share some HTML:

**Component X**

```html
<div class="classB">
  <h2>{{Subtitle}}</h2>
</div>
<div class="classC">
  X_SPECIFIC_HTML
</div>
```

**Component Y**

```html
<div class="classB">
  <h2>{{Subtitle}}</h2>
</div>
<div class="classC">
  Y_SPECIFIC_HTML
</div>
```

I want to define the shared HTML (note the data binding) with a placeholder for the actual component HTML:

```html
<div class="classB">
  <h2>{{Subtitle}}</h2>
</div>
<div class="classC">
  INSERT_COMPONENT_HTML_HERE
</div>
```

So my components can be defined like this:

**Component X**

```html
X_SPECIFIC_HTML
```

**Component Y**

```html
Y_SPECIFIC_HTML
```

Current routes:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'x', component: XComponent },
  { path: 'y', component: YComponent }
];
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using a service to just change the data in your component instead of creating another component?

Comment: Please note the example is extremely simplified. Changing data is unfortunately not a viable solution. The requirement is to handle shared layout.

Comment: I see. It is possible by using another router-outlet inside your shared component/template, can you share how you define your routing?

Comment: Sure, have just edited my question. There is nothing fancy about the routes. I can create a more complete example if needed but it will take some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got help else where...

Sharing HTML is quite easy using "content projection".

The data binding is a bit more tricky and I managed to do so using a BehaviorSubject.

**page-layout.component (the shared HTML)**

```html
<div style="background-color: red;">
  <h2>subtitle: {{subtitle}}</h2>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LayoutService } from '../../services/layout.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-layout',
  templateUrl: './page-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page-layout.component.css']
})
export class PageLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  subtitle = '';

  constructor(private LayoutService: LayoutService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.LayoutService.observable.subscribe(x => {
      if (console) {
        console.log('PageLayoutComponent, subscribe: ' + JSON.stringify(x));
      }
      this.subtitle = x.subtitle;
    });
  }
}
```

**assembly-list.component (a component using the shared HTML)**

```html
<page-layout>
  <p>ToDo</p>
</page-layout>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LayoutService } from '../../services/layout.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'assembly-list',
  templateUrl: './assembly-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./assembly-list.component.css']
})
export class AssemblyListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private LayoutService: LayoutService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.LayoutService.emitTitle(
      'AssemblyListComponent1', 'AssemblyListComponent2'
    );
  }
}
```

**layout-service (the data binding for the shared HTML)**

```js
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

export interface ILayoutServiceData {
  title: string;
  subtitle: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class LayoutService {

  private behaviorSubject: BehaviorSubject<ILayoutServiceData> = 
    new BehaviorSubject({title: null, subtitle: null});

  observable = this.behaviorSubject.asObservable();

  emitTitle(title: string, subtitle: string) {
    if (console) {
      console.log(`LayoutService.emitTitle(\'${title}\', \'${subtitle}\'`);
    }
    const data: ILayoutServiceData = {
      title: title,
      subtitle: subtitle
    };
    this.behaviorSubject.next(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making this work with a `ngModel` in the shared component?